# Add a play / pause buttons on controls for twitter bootstrap carousel plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How can I add a play/pause buttons on controls for twitter bootstrap carousel plugin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.carousel('cycle')` and `.carousel('pause')` methods on your buttons, listening to any event, like this:

```
$("#playButton").click(function() {
    $("#theCarousel").carousel("cycle");
});
$("#pauseButton").click(function() {
    $("#theCarousel").carousel("pause");
});
```